# Vertically align $\bullet$ marker with \blacksquare marker in text

Tags: symbols, vertical-alignment

I use bullets and squares to reference samples in an image.
This is how I use them in text:

```
$\bullet, \blacksquare$

{\LARGE$\bullet$}, $\blacksquare$

{\huge$\bullet$}, $\blacksquare$
```

And this is the result:

[image]

The second one is the best suitable size, but how can I align vertically the square and the bullet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what is meant by "vertical alignment"?  Making the vertical extent of the two symbols the same (i.e., vertical alignment?).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb,scalerel,verbatimbox}
\def\mybullet{\scalerel*{\addvbuffer[-.15pt -.6pt]{$\bullet$}}{\blacksquare}}
\begin{document}
$\mybullet \blacksquare$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\addvbuffer` clips the bullet above and below to something comparable to the square.  Then, the `\scalerel*` scales the clipped `\bullet` to the same vertical extent as the `\blacksquare`.  Below, I show the glyphs surrounded by an `\fbox`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb,scalerel,verbatimbox}
\def\mybullet{\scalerel*{\addvbuffer[-.15pt -.6pt]{$\bullet$}}{\blacksquare}}
\begin{document}
\fboxrule=.1pt
\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\relax
\fbox{$\mybullet$} \fbox{$\blacksquare$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is good for Computer Modern; of course it depends on the size of the bullet in the font.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\textsquarebullet}{%
  \makebox[.5em]{\vrule height 1.05ex depth -.15ex width 0.9ex}%
}

\begin{document}

\textbullet\textsquarebullet

\textsquarebullet\textbullet

\end{document}
```

[image]